# Function stub with Sinon when modules are required inside functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I am trying to stub functions to unit test, but I am not sure if this is possible or I should do changes before I am able to do it. I will try to explain the situation

file `aController.js`

```
...
module.exports = (sqlConnection) => {

...

return {
    ...
    aControllerFunction,
    ...
}

function aControllerFunction(req, res, next) {
  const aService = require('../services/aService')(sqlConnection, req.models)
  ...

  aService.aServiceFunction(req.a, req.b)
}
...
}
...
```

file `aService.js`

```
...
module.exports = (sqlConnection, models) => {

return {
    ...
    aServiceFunction,
    ...
}

...

function aServiceFunction(a, b) {

  
  ...

  models.aModel.update(a)
  sqlConnection.queryAsync(`UPDATE... ${a}`)
  ...
}
...
}
...
```

I want to unit test the functions `aControllerFunction` and `aServiceFunction`.

For `aControllerFunction` I should stub `aService.aServiceFunction`, and for `aServiceFunction.aServiceFunction` I should stub `sqlConnection.queryAsync` and `models.aModel.update`.

Is this possible with this structure, or should I change it before? I tried to do it, but I find hard to stub because the requires are inside the functions.

Comment: Do you return the `aControllerFunction` function, same for `aServiceFunction` function? Otherwise, They are private. Can't get them in the test file.

Comment: @slideshowp2 thanks for the answer, I updated the question. There are exports in the controller and the service, as the functions are being exported. But the requires are in the scope of the function. Is there a way I can stub its behaviors? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to testing `aControllerFunction`, we need additional package [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire). We can use this package to mock function(`serviceFactory`) exported from a module. This called [link seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/).

E.g.

`controllers/aController.js`:

```js
module.exports = (sqlConnection) => {
  return {
    aControllerFunction,
  };

  function aControllerFunction(req, res, next) {
    const aService = require('../services/aService')(sqlConnection, req.models);
    aService.aServiceFunction(req.a, req.b);
  }
};
```

`controllers/aController.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('aController', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const sqlConnection = {};
    const req = { models: {}, a: 'a', b: 'b' };
    const aService = { aServiceFunction: sinon.stub() };
    const serviceFactory = sinon.stub().returns(aService);
    const ControllerFactory = proxyquire('./aController', {
      '../services/aService': serviceFactory,
    });
    const { aControllerFunction } = ControllerFactory(sqlConnection);
    aControllerFunction(req);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(serviceFactory, {}, {});
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(aService.aServiceFunction, 'a', 'b');
  });
});
```

`services/aService.js`:

```js
module.exports = (sqlConnection, models) => {
  return {
    aServiceFunction,
  };

  function aServiceFunction(a, b) {
    models.aModel.update(a);
    sqlConnection.queryAsync(`UPDATE... ${a}`);
  }
};
```

`services/aService.test.js`:

```js
const serviceFactory = require('./aService');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('aService', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const sqlConnection = {
      queryAsync: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const models = {
      aModel: {
        update: sinon.stub(),
      },
    };
    const { aServiceFunction } = serviceFactory(sqlConnection, models);
    aServiceFunction('a', 'b');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(models.aModel.update, 'a');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(sqlConnection.queryAsync, 'UPDATE... a');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
  aController
    ✓ should pass

  aService
    ✓ should pass


  2 passing (35ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 controllers     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  aController.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 services        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  aService.js    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```